# Would it be correct to say "this is of him" instead of "This is his" or "This belongs to him"?

Tags: prepositions, possessives

Would it be correct to say "**This is of him**" instead of "This is his." or "This belongs to him."? 
The same question I would ask about "It is of me." instead "It is mine.", or "It of of you." instead "It is yours.".

For my non native English speaker ears, it sounds weird but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Have you actually seen the phrasing "this is of him/me" used to indicate simple possession anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Stick with the standard possessives: his, mine, ours, yours, etc. Saying "this is of him" is possible in a very abstruse or poetic usage, but nobody—I mean *nobody*—talks like that in everyday life.

This construction is used in a standard way in languages like Spanish, but it simply is not how people talk in English.

Comment: Can you please give an example of such famous poetic using in it? It's very interesting.

Comment: I said it was possible, not famous.

Comment: Indeed, I found 1 result only in Google, for "this is of him".